# Is the Chancellor + Harbinger combo a viable Dominion strategy?

Tags: dominion

From what I can see, the Chancellor (*base set*; allows you to immediately move your deck into your discard pile) coupled with an extra action and the Harbinger (*Dominion Update Pack*; allows you to take any card from the discard pile and put it into your hand) could make a pretty fantastic combo, giving you any card from your deck (as well as giving any reason to use the Chancellor). Is this a viable strategy?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Please check out our [tour] to see how we work. Your question is missing a question, other than a discussion prompt of "has anyone tried this", but we don't do discussion here since there are forums for that (see our [help/dont-ask]). What problem do you need solved exactly?

Comment: I apologize. I' a noob. I'm looking for a combo that would work with the Harbinger in Dominion. It seems that my two ideas are pretty poor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This doesn't work as you are thinking:

- Harbinger has you draw a card *before* you look through your discard pile. This means that when you play Harbinger, the first thing you do is draw a card, which requires you shuffle your discard pile and make a new draw deck. So having played Chancellor first actually makes Harbinger worthless!
- Harbinger doesn't put the card into your hand like you said, it puts it on top of your deck.
- Because Chancellor is a terminal action, and would need to be played before Harbinger, this requires that you first play a Village or another action that gives **+2 Actions**.
- Even if it did work as you were thinking; the end result would be the 1 best card in your deck gets to get played sooner in the shuffle rather than later; or maybe played multiple times within 1 shuffle. This same thing is accomplished with both Scheme and Scavenger by themselves; instead of requiring a multiple card combo.
- A minor point, but as Chancellor was removed from the second edition of Dominion, which is where Harbinger comes from; these 2 cards don't both exist in the same "Dominion world". Of course in casual play they are still both available; but it's likely that online play and tournaments won't have them both.

Comment: Spot-on. Playing Harbinger immediately after Chancellor will result immediately in a reshuffle; thus the Harbinger devolves into a mere cantip.

Comment: That's right... I've been using the Sentry to move a card into the discard pile, then get it back with a Harbinger. I was trying to think of a way to have more control or access to what cards are in the discard pile to make the Harbinger more powerful. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sentry doesn't make much sense as a combo either... if you don't discard the card with Sentry, it would just be on top of your deck anyway. So discarding it, then putting it on top of your deck with Harbinger, doesn't add any value.

Comment: Village + Scavenger + Harbinger works, since Scavenger has you put a card back on your deck, but you still need to have a card worth scrounging through your discard pile for.

Comment: @Deo Chancellor puts your entire deck in the discard pile. When you play Harbinger, you resolve the card top to bottom. That means, **first** you draw one card and then you resolve the ability. Since your whole deck is now in the discard pile and there is nothing to draw, you have to reshuffle. Therefore, the discard pile will be empty and Harbinger won't do anything.

Comment: @Adama. Right. I somehow missed "+1 card" part.

Answer (score 2):

The Chancellor + Harbinger combo is useless because of the + 1 card effect of the Harbinger, but if you're looking for a very similar effect, try using the Scavenger from the Dark Ages expansion. With it "you may put your deck into the discard pile. Look through your discard pile and put one card from it on top of your deck." - Also + 2 money.